# How to add scroll bar directly to JFrame in Swing?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jscrollpane

I know there are various methods to add Scroll to `JPanel` then add the panel to a `JFrame`.

But when I tried to add `JScrollPane` to the frame directly without using a panel, that was an error:

```
window can not be inside the container
```

So in my code, I need to add Scroll directly to my frame.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create Scroll Bar for JFrame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33113073/create-scroll-bar-for-jframe)

Comment: Edit your question and show the code that tries to add the JScrollPane.  Without seeing that, any answers will just be guesses.

Comment: *"So in my code, I need to add Scroll directly to my JFrame."* That doesn't even make sense. Just add (whatever is) the content pane to a scroll pane. A content pane would be a `Container` rather than a `Window`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this example will help:

```
JPanel pnl = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.add(pnl, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);`
```

Comment: Please use code formatting for code and code snippets, structured documents like HTML/XML or input/output.  To do that, **select the text and click the `{}` button at the top of the message posting/editing form.**